# Properties of Outer Product as an Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, vectors

Suppose we have 2 states  $|a \rangle$ and $\langle b|$, and we define an operator $A$ as their outer product, i.e. $A = |a \rangle \langle b|$. I wish to understand certain properties of $A$:

$1)$ Condition for $A$ to be **Hermitian**: All the elements of a state have to be equal in magnitude and purely real. The elements of state $\langle b|$ may not be equal to that of  $|a \rangle$, but they have to be equal to each other.

I arrived at this by assuming a $3\times1$ ket and a $1\times3$ bra. Then, I computed the outer product. After that, I took the adjoint of the outer product, which is $|b \rangle \langle a|$. Then I set the elements of both the matrices equal to each other.

Here are the calculations:
Let $|a \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix}$ and $\langle b| = \begin{bmatrix}b_1^{*}&b_2^{*}&b_3^{*}\end{bmatrix}$.
We get \begin{bmatrix}a_1b_1^{*}&a_1b_2^{*}&a_1b_3^{*}\\a_2b_1^{*}&a_2b_2^{*}&a_2b_3^{*}\\a_3b_1^{*}&a_3b_2^{*}&a_3b_3^{*}\end{bmatrix}
and taking the adjoint of the outer product and computing the matrix, we get:
$$\begin{bmatrix}b_1a_1^{*}&b_1a_2^{*}&b_1a_3^{*}\\b_2a_1^{*}&b_2a_2^{*}&b_2a_3^{*}\\b_3a_1^{*}&b_3a_2^{*}&b_3a_3^{*}\end{bmatrix}$$
$2)$ Condition for $A$ to be a **Projection**: In this case, $A^2 = A$ must hold. But I don't know how to proceed further.

Am I right in concluding the condition for $A$ to be Hermitian? If not, then how should I proceed in this case? Also, how to establish a condition for $A$ to be a projection operator? Can someone help me out in these?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133842/discussion-on-question-by-electrovolt-properties-of-outer-product-as-an-operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... given two vectors (not necessarily normalized) $\vert a\rangle=\sum_i a_i\vert i\rangle$ and $\vert b\rangle=\sum_j b_j\vert j\rangle$, one can construct the explicitly hermitian operator
$$
A=\vert a\rangle\langle b\vert +\vert b\rangle\langle a\vert
$$
There is no restriction on $\vert a\rangle$ or $\vert b\rangle$, i.e. there is no restriction on $a_i$'s or $b_j$'s.

If you insist on having
\begin{align}
A&=\vert a\rangle \langle b\vert\, ,\\
&=\sum_{ij}a_i b_j^*\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert\, ,\\
A^\dagger&= \vert b\rangle\langle a\vert \, ,\\
&=\sum_{ij}a^*_i b_j\vert j\rangle\langle i\vert\, ,\\
\end{align}
Since the diagonal entries must be real, you need something like $b_i=\kappa a_i^*$, where $\kappa\in\mathbb{R}$, although $a_i$ itself may be complex.

For $A$ to be a projector, then
$$
A=\kappa \vert a\rangle\langle a\vert\, ,\qquad 
A^2=\kappa^2 \vert a\rangle\langle a\vert a\rangle\langle a\vert
= \kappa \vert a\rangle\langle a\vert\
$$
so you need $\langle a\vert a\rangle=\frac{1}{\kappa}$.